# Add an "estimated response wait time" to the contact page

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, contact

A lot of us have waited a very long time for the SE team to respond to a contact request via the contact form. Some of us just get impatient waiting, especially if we believe that the issue is (quote) "important". Also, the SE team gets a rather large volume of contact requests within each category.

The automatic response message to contact requests says that a response will be sent within 24 hours. However, the majority of contact requests I've sent overall aren't responded to within 24 hours, some get a response *weeks* later.

Based on this, it would be nice to have a more accurate "estimated response wait time" that loads live based on the current backlog of contact requests made and that have yet to be handled. This way, we reasonably know how much time to expect to wait before we get a response. For example, if this didn't exist, I might start to get anxious if I don't get a response a week later (since I was told I'd get one "within 24 hours"), but not so if the page clearly notes that the expected response time is two weeks. (To avoid confrontation if the team doesn't respond within the "expected" time frame or just a little bit too late, we can pad the number, e.g. say "within 2 weeks" if it's estimated at 10 days.)

Comment: You do get some kind of indication in the 'Ticket Received' e-mail: "A support representative will be reviewing your request and will send you a personal response.(usually within 24 hours)."

Comment: @Glorfindel Looking at the overall response time of my contact requests, only a minority of them have been responded to in 24 hours. Some aren't responded to until 1-2 weeks later.

Comment: Then they need to provide a more realistic estimate. (Not my downvote, BTW)

Comment: @Glorfindel they has never followed this rule. ETA usually ~1-2 weeks )

Comment: Disagree with the feature request: Depending on the time of ticket, response time varies wildly. Serial voting reversals & deletion requests take a couple days, specialized stuff could take months. Automating that in any way would not be better then a flat number.

Comment: @Glorfindel I have waited up to six weeks for an official response.

Comment: I think the post is being downvoted because it sounds like whining. *…However, the majority of contact requests I've sent overall aren't responded to within 24 hours,…* (How many requests have you sent??) It is unrealistic to expect anyone to give a realistic estimated time. Some issues are more complicated than others. My tip is to wait four weeks and then send a follow-up email asking if there have been any developments.

Comment: @Mari-LouA, it doesn't sound professional. If the company can't provide correct ETA, they are doing something wrong, and should fix their processes inside the team.

Comment: @Suvitruf maybe SE lacks resources. You've got to pay someone to read and check up on the complaints and reports etc. I'm not saying I didn't feel a sense of frustration after four weeks of waiting, I am human, but at least I knew they received the report.

Comment: @Mari-LouA yeh, I know that right now they have some problems with it. But Sonic just wants to change ETA in email, at least. Does it that hard?

Comment: @Suvitruf and I am sure Sonic is well aware of the trouble and strife that currently face SE, a bit more patience and understanding wouldn't go amiss.

Comment: I don't think a dynamic ETA is the solution here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is just not possible to calculate. We're not a phone line where customers generally only spend a matter of minutes talking to a representative and we can just plug it into a formula to generate an estimated number of minutes you'll still have to wait. We stick to email because not all requests *can* be handled in a timely manner like that and require more thought or being punted off to someone else who can be dedicated to looking into the issue. Nothing good ever comes from feeling rushed to complete a request.

In general, the majority of tickets we receive are basic requests that do receive a reply within 24 hours. We're talking about very simple things like "I have two accounts I need merged" or "I'm blocked from asking" that require little thought other than looking at a couple pages for verification and clicking buttons. In fact, our average first response time for Community-based tickets has never slipped above the 24-hour mark since we started tracking it weekly after the move to Freshdesk.

However, we do realize that 24 hours is not accurate for every single ticket that comes in. To that end, we modified the auto-responder a couple days ago to read like this:

> We have received your request and a ticket has been created. While we strive to respond to everyone within 24 hours, the nature of community tickets sometimes means longer wait times and we cannot guarantee any response time.